# auto subscribe to "Alert Me" for an item after it is created?

Tags: 2010, alert

Is there a way to make it so automatically register the creator for "Alert Me" when a user adds a new item to a list?

I have a list where users add items. I want them to automatically be alerted when that item changes. They don't want alerts for the entire list so they wouldn't do that. I know they can manually register for alerts to the item they created but I cannot rely on a manual process.

So I want them to automatically be registered for alerts when the item they create is changed.

Comment: Why you need that? You can suscribe to list changues instead item changes.

Comment: @jpussacq: I added some details to explain why.

Comment: I think you need and event receiver in C# to create the alert programatically

Comment: dang! i was hoping to do this with little to no programming. :/ oh well. thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can create a view filter to [Me] and suscribe user to this view

Comment: I'd have to manually subscribe them, right? This list will be accessible by hundreds of folks and it may get 50+ new items a week so I didn't want to have to manually subscribe people as they add items.

Comment: Yes but ony one time per user.

Comment: I think you need code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from (a) writing an event receiver and (b) creating user filtered views and subscribing users to those, you could create a small workflow to do this.

1. Create a workflow that runs when an item is updated
2. Add a "Send an email" activity which send the email to the person who created the item
3. In the body of the email put in values all the fields from your list
4. Publish.

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned. This is what I am currently doing but was hoping to avoid the Workflow route as it requires SP Designer and my company prefers to avoid solutions that require SP Designer. But it is working like that for now.

Comment: Mine too actually. Why not use the visual studio for the workflow?

Comment: We're trying to avoid doing anything too custom that can't be done quickly/easily OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of both answers. I'd say your best bet without code is to create a view that is the `"Created by" = [Me]` and then in the "Send Alerts To" have an AD security group subscribe to that alert. Then you can manage the users that are subscribed to the group based on their membership. Adding a user to the group will allow him/her to receive the alerts, removing a user will essentially unsubscribe them.

Comment: I'd have to manually add/remove from the AD group, right?

Comment: Yes, but that AD group can also be tied to the permissions of the site.